# NPOI XWPF set table column width not working

Tags: apache-poi, npoi

I've been trying to set the column width for my table, but it won't budge. I'm using NPOI from this git https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi.

Currently, my code is:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(reportPath, FileMode.Open);
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(stream);

XWPFTable table;
table = doc.CreateTable(1, 3);
table.SetColumnWidth(0, (ulong)1000);
table.SetColumnWidth(1, (ulong)2000);
table.SetColumnWidth(2, (ulong)3000);

using (var f = File.Create(reportPath)) doc.Write(f);
```

And the generated columns are in the same size having the smallest column size possible. Also, I'm trying to generate a DOCX file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the table width type to make it work.

```
        XWPFTable table1 = doc.CreateTable(1, 3);
        var tblLayout1 = table1.GetCTTbl().tblPr.AddNewTblLayout();
        tblLayout1.type = ST_TblLayoutType.@fixed;
        table1.SetColumnWidth(0, 1000);
        table1.SetColumnWidth(1, 2000);
        table1.SetColumnWidth(2, 3000);
```

The above code works in NPOI 2.5.4